# Why is there so much space at the bottom of my page?

Tags: html, css

I have to make a website for a school project but I am stuck and don't know what to do. After adding my containers it leaves lots of empty space at the bottom of my page.

I don't have much HTML and CSS skills so I haven't been able to try much.

Here is my website link: https://replit.com/@Thom08/CoffeeandCo-2#index.html

It might be a bit messy. I have tried multiple ways but I can't get it to work. I would like it to get rid of all the space at the bottom of my page. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Its because you have a grid, and the last but one (egg) overflows into the next row, so you have a full row of spacing. Make the grid size smaller and the space will disappear. Or, change the height of the items.  To see, right click in the empty space and select inspect..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in your `.box` div you are creating a grid layout with 12 rows and 6 columns, you can check the size with browser dev tools by pressing `F12` and with the select element hover the `div.box` to see how big it is. Your boxes are currently not filling it so there is a lot of empty space.

You could try something like this:

```css
.box{
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}
```

You can play around with the numbers to see how they affect the size and layout.

The `overflow: hidden;` hides any content that "overflows" outside the boundary of the grid.

This is a great [visualizer tool](https://codepen.io/lucas-j-k/pen/PeOyaj) to see how changing the numbers affect the grid.